# Python poetry - how to install optional dependencies?

Tags: python, python-poetry

Python's poetry dependency manager allows specifying optional dependencies via command:

```
$ poetry add --optional redis
```

Which results in this configuration:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.8"
redis = {version="^3.4.1", optional=true}
```

However how do you actually install them? Docs seem to hint to:

```
$ poetry install -E redis
```

but that just throws and error:

```
Installing dependencies from lock file

[ValueError]
Extra [redis] is not specified.
```

Comment: do you also have a `[tool.poetry.extras]` section in your `pyproject.toml` file that defines the extra groups? because that is what the `-E` tag expects, not raw package names.

Comment: @Arne thanks, that's indeed the case! Such an akward specification: you need to specify package with `optional=true` under dependencies section and `group=['package']` under extras section, ugh. Could you add your comment as an answer?

Comment: Sure, I'll also try to explain why it's like this as well, even though the docs aren't very descriptive there.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You need to add a `tool.poetry.extras` group to your `pyproject.toml` if you want to use the `-E` flag during install, as described in [this section](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#extras) of the docs:

```
[tool.poetry.extras]
caching = ["redis"]
```

---

The key refers to the word that you use with `poetry install -E`, and the value is a list of packages that were marked as `--optional` when they were added. There currently is [no support](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/772) for making optional packages part of a specific group during their addition, so you have to maintain this section in your `pyproject.toml` file by hand.

The reason behind this additional layer of abstraction is that extra-installs usually refer to some optional functionality (in this case `caching`) that is enabled through the installation of one or more dependencies (in this case just `redis`). `poetry` simply mimics [`setuptools`' definition of extra-installs](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#declaring-extras-optional-features-with-their-own-dependencies) here, which might explain why it's so sparingly documented.

Comment: For anyone getting the `Extra is not specified` error, you have to run `poetry update` first.

Comment: Is there a short variant so install _all_ extras?

Comment: @StefanFalk no, not unless the package maintainer explicitly creates something like an `[all]` extra. It's not even that easy to simply list all available extras: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4824

Comment: Alternatively for those getting the `Extra is not specified` error, `poetry lock --no-update` is all that is needed to update the lockfile if you don't want to update all your dependencies at the same time.

Comment: as of ~v1.2, `poetry install --all-extras` will install, you guessed it, all the extras (re. @StefanFalk 's question)

Answer (score 36):

I will add that not only you have to have this extras section added by hand, as well your optional dependencies cannot be in dev section.

Example of code that **won't** work:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "yolo"
version = "1.0.0"
description = ""
authors = []

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "2.7"
Django = "*"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
pytest = "*"
ipdb = {version = "*", optional = true}

[tool.poetry.extras]
dev_tools = ["ipdb"]
```

But this **WILL** work:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "yolo"
version = "1.0.0"
description = ""
authors = []

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "2.7"
Django = "*"
ipdb = {version = "*", optional = true}

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
pytest = "*"

[tool.poetry.extras]
dev_tools = ["ipdb"]
```

Comment: Thank you! Is this documented in the `poetry` docs? I couldn't find it and was pulling my hair out trying to figure out why my extras wouldn't install until I found your answer.

Comment: Exactly my thought, Poetry is a bit dry on the topic of extras in documentation so I spend quite some time to figure it all out.

Comment: @Drachenfels I don't understand.... if you put it in `[tool.poetry.dependencies]` isn't it always going to be installed?

Comment: As a application / library maintainer, it kind of makes sense to take "dev-dependencies can't be part of extras" as a given, because dev dependencies are never part of the _distribution_ anyway. What you are discussing are probably distinct dev-setups, where, as far as poetry is concerned, there is only a singular dev-all.

Comment: Jfc, I'm not saying you're doing it wrong, I just want to say that I can see why the poetry authors were blind to this use-case (as was I when I wrote my answer). It's an issue users run into, so it should at least be documented.

Answer (score 9):

This is now possible (with Poetry version 1.2; perhaps even an earlier version), using the "extras" group:

```
poetry add redis --group=extras
```

It will appear in the section

```
[tool.poetry.group.extras.dependencies]
```

which is also newer style (compared to `[tool.poetry.extras]` or `[tool.poetry.extras.dependencies]`

See [the documentation](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#extras). Interestingely, this still follows the older style, `[tool.poetry.extras]`, and doesn't show the use of `poetry add`, but the above result is what I get.

Answer (score 7):

Up-voted Drachenfels's answer.

**Dev dependency could not be optional**, otherwise, no matter how you tweak it with *extras* or retry with `poetry install -E`, it will just never get installed.

This sounds like a bug **but somehow by design**,

> ...this is not something I want to add. Extras will be referenced in the distributions metadata when packaging the project but development dependencies do not which will lead to a broken extras.

— concluded in Poetry PR#606 comment by one maintainer. See here for detailed context: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/pull/606#issuecomment-437943927

---

I would say that I can accept the fact that optional dev-dependency cannot be implemented. However, at least Poetry should warn me when I have such a config. If so, I wouldn't have been confused for a long time, reading each corner of the help manual and found nothing helpful.

---

I found some people did get trap in this problem  ([Is poetry ignoring extras or pyproject.toml is misconfigured?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64048962/is-poetry-ignoring-extras-or-pyproject-toml-is-misconfigured)) but their questions are closed, marked duplicated and re-linked to this question. Thus I decided to answer here and give more details about this problem.

Comment: I've been caught by this as well, with pip `package[extra]` tends to install the "correct" version of extra and many packages I install use it in this manner, so I'll always use it in preference to installing `package` and `extra` separately. I guess poetry should resolve this properly but when I type `poetry add package[extra]` I expect it to treat both as required.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and it seems that the at least from version 1.4.2, we can use optional `groups`. I first add the optional group to `pyproject.toml` file:

```ini
[tool.poetry.group.optionalgroup]
optional = true

[tool.poetry.group.optionalgroup.dependencies]
```

Then, add the desried package to this group:

```bash
poetry add optionalpackage --group optionalgroup
```

And then install it with this command

```bash
poetry install --with optionalgroup
```

Check [optional groups](https://python-poetry.org/docs/master/managing-dependencies/#optional-groups) in poetry docs for more information.